# Mouse events not fired by event listener using Syn.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get Syn.js to do a programmatic mouse movement to use in the Specs of my app.

I need to track and test a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave`. Made a simple Spec but could not get it to work, no event is fired.

Any pointers to what I might be missing? or how to make the events fire?

My testcase:

(**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/g1wjkjw5/)

JS

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseenter', log);
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseleave', log);
var events = {};

function log(e) {
    console.log(e.type); // never fires... :/
    events[e.type] = true;
}

setTimeout(function () {
    syn.move({
        from: {clientX: 400, clientY: 400},
        to: {clientX: 50, clientY: 50},
        duration: 1000
    }, document.body);

    console.log('Syn fired');
}, 200);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(events); // this gets empty
}, 2000);
```

CSS

```
div#target {
    background: #ccf;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bitovi/syn/master/dist/syn.js"></script>
<div id="target" style="float: left; padding: 100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mozilla probably won't let you](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/dom/events/EventStateManager.cpp#579)

Looking at the [Syn.js](https://github.com/bitovi/syn/blob/master/dist/syn.js#L2289) source code, the events you are after aren't simulated at all.

[jQuery does what the others have suggested](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a5e1c9b44c971fd7046d9a95bd0810e50840b663/src/event.js#L706)

Keep in mind that originally mouse enter/leave was proprietary to Internet Explorer, and that jQuery emulated it. Its only quite recently become ubiquitous. [1](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)

Here is a [jsfiddle using a modified Syn.js](http://jsfiddle.net/g1wjkjw5/10/) to achieve what you asked for.

Simply changed the event names:

```
if (last !== el && el && last) {
    var options = syn.helpers.extend({}, point);
    options.relatedTarget = el;
    syn.trigger(last, 'mouseleave', options);
    options.relatedTarget = last;
    syn.trigger(el, 'mouseenter', options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this and suggesting a extensio to Syn to handle mouseenter and mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 console.log('mouse inside');
});

document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseout', unction(){
console.log('mouse left');
});

var events = {};



setTimeout(function () {
syn.move({
    from: {clientX: 600, clientY: 300},
    to: {clientX: 50, clientY: 50},
    duration: 1000
}, document.body);

console.log('Syn fired');
}, 200);

setTimeout(function () {
console.log(events);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for checking this. What do you mean by `console.log('clickmade');`? its a mouse enter/leave event I wish to simulate...

Comment: Im sorry, probably because its friday so the end of week. but you can replace that with mouseinside and mouseoutside :) @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs the syn library fires the events `mouseover` and `mouseout` for hover events:

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseover', log);
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseout', log);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g1wjkjw5/2/

You can transform these events in your log function if you really want to log them as mouseenter/mouseleave

```
function log(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseover") {
        events["mouseenter"] = true
    } else if (e.type == "mouseout") {
        events["mouseleave"] = true
    } else {
        events[e.type] = true;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1wjkjw5/4/

EDIT:

In order to capture actual mouse[enter|leave] events you could capture the mouseover/mouseout events and transform them into the proper event object:

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseover', transformEvent);
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseout', transformEvent);

function transformEvent(e) {
    var newEvent = false;
    if (e.type == "mouseover") {
        newEvent = "mouseenter";
    } else if (e.type == "mouseout") {
        newEvent = "mouseleave";        
    }

    if (newEvent) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var event = new MouseEvent(newEvent, {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': true
          });
        e.toElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1wjkjw5/8/

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I would like to use the DOM3 event `mouse[enter|leave]` and have Syn fire that event, any suggestions there?

Comment: Updated. This is about the only way I can think to do it although there may be other solutions